# AS3 - Does timers interrupt current code?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm just curious about the implementation of timers as flash is single threaded.

If a timer event should fire, does it interrupt the current executing code, fire the event and then go back, or does it do something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Adobe's documentation:

> If events occur during other parts of the execution cycle, the runtime
>   queues up those events and dispatches them in the next frame.

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a61a52657a1274ff66899-8000.html